# Next Js 13 beta build is slow on server

Tags: node.js, next.js

I have created an app with next js 13 (beta). The build works normally when none is using the site. But when a lot of users visit the website at the same time, the site becomes slower. Sometimes I cannot even enter the site.

I don't know if this is a problem with next js or node js server.

I am using:
Node 18.14.1 and
Next js 13 beta (with app directory)

Can anyone help me with any solutions to solve the speed issue?

Comment: Is it happening for first time hit or all the time?

Comment: All the time, but only when a lot users try to use the site at the same time.